# How to create a list template by using CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model, list-template, csom

For creating a list template programmatically by using server object, I'm using the SaveAsTemplate() function.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{
  using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(strSiteURL))
  {
    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
    {
      oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

      SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists[strListName];
      string bkpTemplateName = "bkp" + strListName + ".stp";
      list.SaveAsTemplate(bkpTemplateName, bkpTemplateName.Replace(".stp",""), "Description", true);

      list.Update();
      oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
  }
});
```

But, is there a way to do the same by using CSOM?

Answer (score 5):

The method `SaveAsTemplate` is not exposed in `CSOM API`, there is a general suggestion opened: [Expose List.SaveAsTemplate() for CSOM API](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6527561-expose-list-saveastemplate-for-csom-api)

Basically you can create lists using already existing custom templates, but programmatically you cannot create new ones.

```
Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
Web.ListTemplates
```

What you can do is define the list schema xml and use it every time you have to create a new list programmatically, using the ListCreationInformation CustomSchemaXml property.

Comment: but exporting list schema to XML doesnt give us the data, it just just gives the schema , right? STP gives us the whole thing. Just confirming.