# Save list as template using client object model in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-template

Is it possible to save list as a template using CSOM?

We need to create a list template every weekend in SharePoint Online. I thought of using task scheduler with a console application but could not find a way to save a list as a template.

For full trust code we have `saveListAsTemplate` method, but I couldn't find any in CSOM.

What are my options?

Comment: hi rohit facing same issues , found some articles on below url:- http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153989/how-to-create-a-list-template-by-using-csom#